# Trying to add an element to a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

i've tried to add an element from class type to an empty dynamic array, but nothing happens, nor it changes the counter after adding one element.
This is the function

```
void Bank::addCustomer(const Customer& newCustomer) {

    Customer* temp = new Customer[getCustomerCount()+1]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < getCustomerCount() + 1 ; ++i) {
        if (getCustomerCount() != 0) {
            temp[i] = customers[i];
        }
    }

    ++customerCount;
    setCustomerCount(customerCount);
    delete[] customers; 
    customers = temp;

    customers[customerCount] = newCustomer; 
    //log
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: @Shushu At least this for loop for (int i = 0; i < getCustomerCount() + 1 ; ++i) { invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Shushu This if statement if (getCustomerCount() != 0) { does not make a sense.

Comment: @Shushu This assignment customers[customerCount] = newCustomer; again invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Shushu The function in whole does no make a sense because there are used the variable customerCount and the function getCustomerCount at the same time. So the question should be closed as senseless.

Comment: `std::vector<Customer>` -- This solves all of the problems.  If you say you can't use this, this is one reason why students drop using C++ and pick up Java or some other language.

Comment: as a side note, I strongly suggest you adopt a naming convention for member fields (`m_customerCount`, `_customerCount`, `customerCount_` are the common ones)

Comment: Note how pm100's suggestions don't lead with an underscore and follow it with an uppercase letter. [That would be bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is exceeding the bounds of the old array if it is not empty. And your assignment of the `newCustomer` is exceeding the bounds of the new array.

Try this instead:

```
void Bank::addCustomer(const Customer& newCustomer) {

    int count = getCustomerCount(); 
    Customer* temp = new Customer[count + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        temp[i] = customers[i];
    }
    temp[count] = newCustomer; 

    delete[] customers; 
    customers = temp;

    ++customerCount;

    //log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you mean:

```
void addCustomer(const Customer& newCustomer) {
    int old_customer_count = getCustomerCount();
    int new_customer_count = old_customer_count + 1;

    Customer* temp = new Customer[new_customer_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < new_customer_count; ++i) {
        temp[i] = customers[i];
    }

    setCustomerCount(new_customer_count);
    delete[] customers;
    customers = temp;
    customers[old_customer_count] = newCustomer;
}
```

but as someone said, in real code you should an `std::vector` for the customers collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **vector** for dynamic array. arry cann't be dynamic.  *push_back()* function can be used for adding element to vector.